# How to replace Java linewrap with HTML linewrap?

Tags: javascript, java, html, css, angularjs

I have a response that I get from a Java server that has some line wrap characters. I am binding it to a HTML span element and displaying it like so

```
<span>{{error}}</span>
```

Rendered as -

```
<span class="ng-binding">"This port is currently in use. /n/nWould you like to proceed?"</span>
```

I'm trying to replace the /n/n with HTML understandable line break but not having any luck.

I tried replacing the "error" string with

```
replace("/n/n", "<br \>")
```

and other variations of the above.

Also tried using

```
white-space: pre-line

<pre>
```

But none of it works. I'm doubtful if this is because the string is rendered within quotes in the HTML but cant figure out why. Normally when I bind a string, it is displayed without quotes.

```
<span>{{error}}</span>
```

usually translates to

```
<span>Some error</span>
```

and not

```
<span>"Some Error"</span>
```

Could this be the problem? If it is, why is it happening? I don't see quotes anywhere else in the markup for bound text. Or is there a different solution for line wrap?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It works for me when I use the `replace` method. You are aware that this method returns a new `String` object, rather than modify the existing object, right? That might be your problem. You will also need to insert another "\" character into the replacement substring due to escape sequences.

Comment: I tried doing error=error.replace("/n/n", "<br /\>") and different combinations of "\" and "/" but no luck.

Comment: What's the output of that method when you try that? The replacement string is supposed to be `"<br \\>"`

Comment: This is the output string and the rendered markup text
<span class="ng-binding">"This port is currently in use. <br \>Would you like to proceed?"</span>

Comment: That's the desired output right? Or am I missing something

Comment: @yazz Looks like you are almost there. Check the self closing `br` tag syntax (or do not even close it). Make sure Angular allows you to pass raw HTML.